# How to find a string in a file and moving the cursor to it using a macro in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

As per the question. Using a macro in sublime text how can I:

1. Find a matching string
2. Move to the end of line where that string is found
3. Insert something at the end of line

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in a single step using the built-in macros, because Sublime macros don't support find and replace out of the box. You can manage it easily enough in two steps, though:

Given the following trivial example:

```
<ul>
    <li>one
    <li>two
    <li>three
</ul>
```

If I wanted to close these tags, I could:

- type `</li>`, select it, then cut it to my clipboard
- start recording with <kbd>ctrl-q</kbd>
- <kbd>cmd-rightArrow</kbd> to move to the end of the line
- <kbd>cmd-v</kbd> to paste
- <kbd>ctrl-q</kbd> to stop recording
- <kbd>cmd-f</kbd> and enter a search string (possibly regex!)
- hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to focus on the selection back in the document

Now you can alternate:

- <kbd>shift-ctrl-q</kbd> to play back the macro
- <kbd>cmd-g</kbd> to advance to the next match

Of course, for such a simple example, using multiple cursors (maybe with [SelectUntil](https://github.com/xavi-/sublime-selectuntil)) would be a quicker, simpler solution.

For more complex or repeatable operations, [RegReplace](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/) may be useful.